# Reading random columns from a csv file: Django

Tags: python, django, csv

From a csv file, I want to read only 3 columns:

```
{Id, name, approve}
```

But when the user uploads a csv file, they could end up giving extra information in a random order e.g:

```
{approve, reject, Id, foreign, name, approve, description}
```

So far I have only been able to match if the "allowed headers" are present in the uploaded csv (the code below works).

But how can I read the data from these "allowed headers" columns (considering their index position might be in a random order) ?

My code (forms.py)

```
def clean(self):       
        uploaded_csv_file = self.cleaned_data['csv_file']
        allowed_headers = {'id','name','approve'}
        validation_errors = []

        if uploaded_csv_file:
            filename = uploaded_csv_file.name
            if not filename.endswith(settings.FILE_UPLOAD_TYPE):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Please upload .csv extension files only")

            # django InMemoryUploadedFile returns bytes and we need strings
        rows = csv.reader(StringIO(uploaded_csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')))
        header = next(rows)

        csv_fields = set(header)
        csv_fields = {field.lower() for field in csv_fields}
        result =  all(elem in allowed_headers  for elem in csv_fields) # Check if list1 contains all elements of list2 using all()

        if not result:
            validation_errors.append(
                ValidationError('Your file could not be processed. You should provide %s columns in the file' % ', '.join(allowed_headers)))
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can use pandas package to read it simple.

Comment: ive been thinking about that. Do you think there could be an impact on the performance ? pandas versus simple csv reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can use `csv.DictReader` and access each column by name, eg:

```
allowed_headers = {'id','name','approve'}
# ...
csvin = csv.DictReader(StringIO(uploaded_csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')))
# lowercase all fieldnames before doing anything else
csvin.fieldnames = [name.lower() for name in csvin.fieldnames]
if not allowed_headers.issubset(csvin.fieldnames):
    # ... required fields aren't present

for row in csvin:
    name = row['name'] # ... etc
```

Comment: in my file the header can be Id or ID or id. And in the code I have to specify the name of the header. I dont know how to do a lowercase matchup. any tips here ?

Comment: I found this: https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-implement-case-insensitive-csv-dictreader-in-python/ but I dont want to override a super class (i could, but I dont think this is the most efficient way)

Comment: @Umair Before you start reading any rows do: `csvin.fieldnames = [name.lower() for name in csvin.fieldnames]` that way the dictionary will always have lowercase column names and if you have your `allowed_headers` all lower case - you should be fine.